# Generating pairs of values from a map with values as list in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, web

I have the below map.

```
map = { a: [ 11, -11 ], b: [ 'hello', 10 ] }
```

How do I get the below output from this map?

```
(11,'hello)
(-11,10)
```

Note that the number of keys in the map is dynamic. As of now there are 2 keys. I need to get the logic to work for any number of keys and any number of elements in the list for each key. Thanks.

Comment: what is that output for? Is it supposed to be string? It's not valid javascript as shown ..maybe you want `[11,'hello']`?

Comment: Will the position be fixed? Will 'a' always take the second value from 'b'? And the 3rd value from 'c'? If not, you'll need a way to have the keys relate to eachother, so we know which key will relate to which other key.

Comment: The output is a string.

Comment: the position is fixed - 1,1 or 2,2, or 3,3 . First value of one list with first value of second. second value of first list with second value of second list and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of an object are traversed [in an arbitrary way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted_added_or_modified_properties), with that in mind and also assuming that each nested array has the same length you can do something like this:

```js
var map = { a: [ 11, -11 ], b: [ 'hello', 10 ] }

// properties of the map to array e.g. ['a', 'b', ...]
var keys = Object.keys(map)

var ans = []
// k = the length of each nested array
// handles the case of an empty map {}
var k = (keys[0] && map[keys[0]].length)|0

for (var i = 0; i < k; i += 1) {
  var transpose = []
  for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j += 1) {
    transpose.push(map[keys[j]][i])
  }
  ans.push(transpose)
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(ans))
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop though all to create output shown as string

```
var keys = Object.keys(map);
var out = map[keys[0]].map(function(item, i){
    return '(' + [item, map[keys[1]][i]].join() + ')';    
}).join('<br>');
```

Produces:

```
(11,hello)
(-11,10)
```

```js
var map = { a: [ 11, -11 ], b: [ 'hello', 10 ] }


   
var keys = Object.keys(map);
var out = map[keys[0]].map(function(item, i){
    return '('+ [item, map[keys[1]][i]].join()   + ')';    
}).join('<br>');

document.body.innerHTML= out;
```